# Calculator for Dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, calculator

I want to make a calculator for my data.

Basically I have multiple measurements in different .csv files that are named as their physical representation (temperature_1, current_1, voltage_1 ecc.) and I am trying to make a calculator in python that given a certain expression [e.g. (current_1 * voltage_1) + (current_2 * voltage_2)] is able to load the data from each file and evaluates the result of the expression on the dataframes.

I already made simple functions in order to sum, subtract, multiply and divide dataframes but I am stuck on how to handle complex expressions like the sum of many multiplications [e.g. (current_1 * voltage_1) + (current_2 * voltage_2) + (current_3 * voltage_3) ecc.].

I tried to use a parser but still got no result.

Somebody has any idea on how to handle this?

Note: all the .csv have 2 columns, time and measurement, the number of rows are the same and the acquisition time is at the same timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. For anybody who will need similar functions i report here the solution in steps

1. Write your equation with the name of your files. E.g. current_1 * voltage_1 (you need file current_1.csv, voltage_1.csv)
2. parse your equation with any parser. I used py_expression_eval.
3. Extract the variables from the equation (variables = parser.parse(equation).variables())
4. iterate over the variables and at each step:

   - load the data in a dataframe
   - insert the column of the measurement in general dataframe
   - change the name of that column to the name of your file (e.g. current_1)

   by doing this you will obtain a dataframe with columns: time, measurement_1, measurement_2 ecc.
5. Use df.eval('result= ' + expression, inplace=True) to evaluate your initial expression using the columns you have added to the general dataframe

Hope this helps somebody